# How can I access my ISP's server

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am using a Broadband Cable Internet connection. My ISP give me a LAN cable that I can connect to my PC's lan port or Laptop lan port. Also, My ISP's have a Local server, that I can use for Movie, Games etc Download. For using it I need to type the server ip address in my browser that is 10.111.200.11 & 10.112.200.11 . Its running fine without any problem.

But, My problem is here ....

When I use the cable in my Dlink Wireless Router (DIR-605L) to make my internet WiFi. The internet is working fine but, I can't access my ISP's server ip that is 10.111.200.11 & 10.112.200.11. My browser showing

```
"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 10.111.200.11"
```

So, how can I access the server ip address.

My router ip address is: 192.168.0.1 & My PC IP address is: 192.168.0.100 - Laptop is 101 - My Phone is 102 ..

Thank You

Comment: IF it works fine without the router, I'd think that your router blocks RFC1918 addresses, which arguably is a good thing, but not for you. You can ask Dlink customer support about this, or install custom firmware on the router (OpenWRT or DD-wrt), or get a new router.

Comment: Hello Jorn, Thank your for your reply. But, The Ip address 10.111.200.11 is a local ip address form the isp local network. so It is visit able from there network, my router make a new local network here. so I can't visit there local ip. so have any router configuration for accessing the isp ips?

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe you have a NAT modem Router that only lets you use one subnet. Yours being 192.168.x.y and it won't let you access another subnet 10.x.y.z

Comment: Maybe you are right, but, How can I fix it ? Have any Idea ?

Comment: There is no way for anybody to know how to fix this, without having experience with exactly the same equipment that you have. There is no technical reason why this won't work, but as I stated before, Dlink may block access to private networks on the WAN side.

Comment: Can you go via your PC connected to the network cable then run command prompt tool tracert to the location "tracert 10.111.200.11"? You can try the same on your laptop over the wireless and post both results back to give me some further insight in to the network, thanks.

Comment: @JEWELAHMMED: Which IP do your laptop/PC have when you connect the cable from the ISP directly to them? So you are literally only getting a single LAN cable from your ISP, no router in between or anything?

Comment: @CharlesH Please see the image: http://i.imgur.com/qVp52R2.jpg

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you make it past the router. Are you sure it works without the router?

Comment: Yes, when I connect the cable in my pc directly it's working fine.

Comment: @TheUser1024 I can't understood about your question, Because I very new. Please make me more clear.

Comment: @JEWELAHMMED: no problem, i will try :-) You said you connect the cable from the ISP to your PC directly and then it works. Please do the tracert CharlesH suggested when you can access your ISPs server successfully. That might make things more clear. Is it correct that the cable from the wall goes into your computer with no other devices in the middle? Also: Have you asked your ISP about this issue?

Comment: @TheUser1024 No, Just they give me a cable like this: http://goo.gl/0otXBG

When I connected the cable in my PC port I can visit there server ip.

But, I connected the cable in my WiFi Router I can't visit the server ip.

Comment: @JEWELAHMMED: That is (as Martin already noted) an Ethernet cable with RJ-45 connector(s). Your PC will most likely have a 10.x.x.x IP when you hook it up directly to the ISPs cable.

Comment: Thank you all friend I got my answer form @IAmTheSquidward Reply.

Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Can you access other sites on the internet? Is everything giving you a problem, or just the connection to that server? Perhaps the modem learned the MAC address of the first machine attached to it (some ISPs provide modems / services that care about this) and needs to be reset or given time to update?

Comment: Everything is, I will not able to access my ISP ips for some reason.
Please read "2 Answers" for more details.

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10.x.x.x address that your ISP is providing is one of their internal local addresses that cannot be accessed from outside their network.  The reason you can connect when you are not using your router is because you are directly attached to their 10.x.x.x network/subnet.

Your DLink box is creating a new network, a 192.168.x.x, which is on a different subnet as the 10.x.x.x.  To access the 10.x.x.x address that your ISP provided you with, you need to create a routing table record in your router.  This can normally only be done with custom firmwares, as you do not have access to a CLI or SSH.

If you need to use a router *and* access this other address, you need to invest in a router that can be installed with custom firmware, such as DD-WRT or Tomato.

Comment: Thank You very much @IAmTheSquidward, Now I got my perfect answer.

Comment: @JEWELAHMMED: You might also want to hit the "useful" +1 button (the upwards arrow above the number next to the answer) if you're already resorting to strong language like "perfect" ;-)

Comment: @JEWELAHMMED Are you suddenly able to access the site now? Howcome?

Comment: You write "The 10.x.x.x address that your ISP is providing " <-- No, that range is not provided by the ISP.  And if he is getting a 10.x.x.x IP then i'm sure he is connected to a Router. One could ask, what advantage he sees in having a Dlink router given that he already has a router.

Comment: @barlop By provided, I just mean that his IP said to connect to that address. And he doesn't necessarily have a router. Some ISPs lease out modems with just a single port - thereby directly connecting you to their internal network, and they do the routing for you.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward Whether your "modem" has a single port or not, whether it does NAT or not, whether your modem came from your ISP or not, does not change what the ISP does / how your ISP routes things once it gets to them. The ISP gives you 1 or more public IPs. You can use them and be directly connected to the Internet. Or you can use NAT which still uses a public address from the ISP. The ISP ALWAYS and ONLY provides 1 or more public IP addresses.

Comment: This answer does not seem to make sense. From the ISPs point of view, any machine behind a router with NAT will be accessing their server from the IP address that they give you. It does not matter that your LAN is a separate network - that's the point of NAT and a router. To me this sounds more like a firewall issue on the router; or perhaps the modem picked up the MAC address of the first machine that was attached to it and is doing some kind of specific filtering or needs to be reset / given time to update.

Comment: @TheUser1024 Please see it ... http://i.imgur.com/vhguuRq.jpg

Answer (score -2):

First of all we need to get some of that terminology correct.

- Broadband Connection is a connection that uses your Copper Phone line
- Cable Connection Uses RG-6 Coaxial Cable to provide faster speeds with more Bandwidth
- there is no such thing as a Broadband Cable Connection, so i'm going to assume that you mean Broadband Connection
- LAN Cable is not the correct Term.
  LAN is the Network (Local Area Network) , the Yellow or Blue Cable that you got is commonly called an Ethernet Cable, but more specifically it's an 8 Pin UTP Cable and the Port it plugs into is called an ETHERNET PORT not a LAN Port, it's an Ethernet Port that allows your computer to connect to your LAN.

This all sounds normal so far. Then you said that you plugged the Ethernet cable into your Router to get WiFi

Now, You generally have 2 Types of connections in a Home Network - Wireless (WiFi)  or  Wired (Ethernet/LAN).

It doesn't make sense that you would plug in a cable to get WiFi. So, for now,  Just plug int the Ethernet cable to your Router and to to your computer..

Let's worry about Wireless later.  Now, you need to confirm that actually have an internet connection.

Now, you said that you can get to google, and Make sure that you can get to other websites also. that will mean that your connection is working from your computer to your router without issues, that means its a server issue.  Now, Please understand that FROM YOUR POINT OF VIEW, Unless the ISP has put their Server in your living room, inside of your LAN,  which i really doubt then the server is NOT a Local Server.

if you have to access it via the internet, to you it's not LOCAL it's Remote to them it's LOCAL and you probably had some support person who didn't have half a clue, told you it was their local server to them IT IS LOCAL, to you IT'S REMOTE

If you're trying to get to an IP Address via browser,

1. confirm that the IP Address is correct with your ISP
2. Type it in the address bar of Chrome. If it doesn't work, try other browsers and see if it works there - it could just be an issue with Chrome, the browser could be in offline mode.
3. Open a command prompt and type in

   ```
   ping 10.111.200.11
   ```

   and see if you get a result and repeat this for the other IP Address, if you get a successful ping, but the browser wont open it, then it's a browser issue.  Sometimes it wont ping, but. only because the server is setup to not allow ping, so take that with a grain of salt.
4. Call your ISP and ask them why you can't access the site, it might be a secure server
   they may have technical issues, you may need to logon at a logon page,

do these things and get back to me, with your results

Comment: @JasonC You're right. Martin, Feel free to take it to [meta] or rollback the edit if you don't like it. And no, I don't get into rollback wars.

Comment: @Martin You can roll back your edits with the link I mentioned above. "Rollback wars" refers to two people constantly rolling back each others edits. The diamond is the one to the right of Sathya's name, which signifies a community moderator. And, it is not possible to determine who down-voted an answer, but down votes happen so do not take them personally. :) (Also "@username" in the front means I was talking to somebody else, you can type "@whoever" to direct a reply to a certain user.)

Comment: @Martin: I downvoted this answer (others did too, I'm not the only one). Your very first point is factually incorrect. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband): "The term broadband refers to the wide bandwidth characteristics of a transmission medium and its ability to transport multiple signals and traffic types simultaneously. The medium can be coax, optical fiber, twisted pair, DSL local telephone networks or wireless." So claiming that it can only be on the PSTN telephone line is factually incorrect. I don't have time to go through the rest to point out the other errors.

Comment: I think the advice at the end (the 4 steps) is good advice regardless of the correctness of the first part.

Comment: @allquixotic Mate, i was speaking to a Newbie, not an engineer OK and what i said was "there is no such thing as a Broadband Cable Connection, so i'm going to assume that you mean Broadband Connection" .. did you not understand that i meant that from the point of view that ... The Newbie obviously had 2 things confused my aim was (on a basic level) to clarify it for him, Jesus Christ are you guys even reading what i wrote, did you understand it or are just taking everything out of context, My Answer was catering for the person asking the question,I'm over this conversation seriously this is BS

Comment: @Martin An answer is for everyone, if you have statements that are not factually correct, the make them factually correct